# Why this query causes a deadlock?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I use this query to distribute rows between concurrent workers:

```
SET @update_id := 0;
UPDATE tablename
    SET processed = -1, id = (SELECT @update_id := id)
    WHERE processed = 0
    LIMIT 1
SELECT @update_id as id;
```

Sometimes it threw a deadlock exception and I've just restarted it. But with high enough worker count it starts to get deadlock almost every time and become stuck in retry loop. How to rewrite it properly?

Answer (score 0):

You should have `processed` column indexed and try this query

```
SET @update_id := (SELECT id FROM tablename t WHERE processed = 0 LIMIT 1);
SET @updated_id := 0;
UPDATE tablename
    SET processed = -1, id = (SELECT @updated_id := id)
WHERE 
        id = @update_id
        AND processed = 0;

SELECT @updated_id as id;
```

You might need to run to this several times until you get none zero updated_id. You need to handle the situation when there're no unprocessed records as well.

Alternative approach:

Assuming each process has an unique @process_Id and it only processes one record at a time and delete it or set processed to -1 after processing.

```
UPDATE tablename SET processed = @process_id WHERE processed = 0 LIMIT 1;    
SELECT id FROM tablename t WHERE processed = @process_id;
```

Comment: Are you sure this should work properly? What if row is modified after select subquery returns but before update happens? Should I check return value and restart query if 0 rows are modified?

Comment: `AND processed = 0 ` should prevent it. 
yes, if 0 rows are modified or 0 is returned, you should restart query. You may need to add check that there's any row with `processed = 0 `, so you don't have endless loop.

Alternative approach is to set ProcessId instead of -1 then it might simplify things, in any case you have to deal with crashed processes.

`update tn set processed=<ProcId> where processed=0 limit 1;
select id from tn where processed=<ProcId>`

Comment: `General error: 1093 You can't specify target table 'tablename' for update in FROM clause`